# How to run a function when datepiker start to display?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I try change font family of year when click on  the input of datepiker.I can not use css for do this .I use this code but don't work currently.Please advice.

```
   $("#DepartureDateM_Flight").datepicker({
    todayHighlight: true,
    isRTL: true,
    rtl:true,
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    minDate: 1,
    altField: '#alternate2',
    altFormat: 'DD، d MM yy',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    regional: '',
    startView: function () {
        $('.ui-datepicker-month,.ui-datepicker-year').css('font-family', 'Arial');
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You are using bootstrap datepicker, but ordinary datepicker css styles. It aint gonna work....

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) event:

```
$("#DepartureDateM_Flight").click(function() {
  $('.ui-datepicker-title').css('font-family', 'Arial');
});
```

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/0wx2zaLo/)

**Note**: A mobile-friendy alternative is the [`focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) event.

Comment: This worked but when change month the font of  .ui-datepicker-title changed . I found better way for this  case. I add a class to div wrapper date piker and use css for change font. This way work currently.Thank you for answering.